# Perl: How to print a random section (word definition) from a dictionary file

Tags: perl

I want to print a random new word English in dictionary file in terminal Unix by Perl. I want to select and print a random line and 2 follow lines.

But my code doesn't complete this work.

Please help me to improve it.

#### An example of the output I wish:

```
@inspire: ....

ghk

lko...
```

#### Dictionary file:

```
@inspiration: mean....

abc def...

ghk lmn
...

@inspire: ....

ghk

lko...

@people: ...

...
```

The complete dictionary file is here [anhviet109K.txt](http://www.mediafire.com/download/g4266s1aldm0uma/anhviet109K.txt). It's about 14MB

#### My code:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Copy qw(copy move);

my $files = 'anhviet109K.txt';
my $fh;
my $linewanted = 16 + int( rand( 513796 - 16 ) );

# 513796: number of lines of file dic.txt

open( $fh, "<", $files ) or die "cannot open < $fh: $!";

my $del   = " {2,}";
my $temp  = 0;
my $count = 0;

while ( my $line = <$fh> ) {

    if ( ( $line =~ "@" ) && ( $. > $linewanted ) ) {
        $count = 4;
    }
    else {
        next;
    }

    if ( $count > 0 ) {
        print $line;
        $count--;
    }
    else {
        last;
    }
}

close $fh;
```

Comment: Please give a proper example of your dictionary file that we can use to test with. The whole things is only a few MB so you could post it on [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/)

Comment: Tks Borodin, I have add my dic link for test.

Comment: Thank you very much. That helps a lot

Comment: Tks Borodin. Very useful code.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this, perhaps?

Your data has helped me to exclude the header entries in your dictionary file

This program finds the location of all of the entries (lines beginning with `@`) in the file, then chooses one at random and prints it

*Tốt học tiếng Anh may mắn*

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Fcntl ':seek';

use constant FILE => 'anhviet109K.txt';

open my $fh, '<', FILE or die qq{Unable to open "@{[FILE]}" for input: $!};

my @seek;  # Locations of all the definitions

my $addr = tell $fh;
while ( <$fh> ) {
    push @seek, $addr if /^\@(?!00-)/;  
    $addr = tell $fh;
}

my $choice = $seek[rand @seek];

seek $fh, $choice, SEEK_SET;
print scalar <$fh>;
while ( <$fh> ) {
    last if /^\@/;
    print;
}
```

#### output

```
@finesse /fi'nes/
*  danh từ
- sự khéo léo, sự phân biệt tế nhị
- mưu mẹo, mánh khoé
*  động từ
- dùng mưu đoạt (cái gì); dùng mưu đẩy (ai) làm gì; dùng mưu, dùng kế
=to finesse something away+ dùng mưu đoạt cái gì
```

Comment: Very nice approach. I'm always afraid of `seek` and `tell` because I assumed they introduce a ±1 problem but your solution is so simple and elegant. Plus it reveals your 2nd passion: languages :-)

Comment: @PerlDog: As long as you ignore the actual values returned by `tell`, and only use them to feed back into `seek` (that is, use them as black-box objects) everything will work fine. And thank you, but I know far fewer languages than I would like. My main interest is in formalising languages and dialects so that they may be treated as data. Unfortunately the technology started with western languages and only later tried to squeeze Asian and African languages and dialects into the same pattern. Inevitably it didn't work, and to be honest the Unicode programme has been a huge step forward

Comment: I admit I haven't used seek/tell very often. You use it like _"freezing"_ and _"thawing"_ the file pointer. I'll consider that next time. Seems easy. /// Languages are really interesting and I also like dialects a lot but I don't deal with them "scientifically". I just enjoy them.

Comment: @PerlDog: I wouldn't compare it to freeze/thaw, it's simply a matter of gathering metadata about the file. It's an alternative to reading the whole file into an array of text blocks, which would be a perfectly valid solution here. I guess the wind was blowing in a different direction today! It's basically how [Tie::File](https://metacpan.org/pod/Tie::File) works. Many damn that module for being slow, but as always it's perfectly fine unless its *too slow* for your application. I think it's a shame it's not used much more, as it allows you to edit a file as an array of lines. Magic!

Comment: As PerlDog alluded - thank you for the expose on seek/tell.

Answer (score 2):

A single pass approach:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

open my $fh, '<:utf8', 'anhviet109K.txt';

my $definition = '';
my $count;
my $select;

while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    if ($line =~ /^@(?!00-)/) {
        ++$count;
        $select = rand($count) < 1;
        if ($select) {
            $definition = $line;
        }
    }
    elsif ($select) {
        $definition .= $line;
    }
}

# remove blank line that some entries have
$definition =~ s/^\s+\z//m;

binmode STDOUT, ':utf8';
print $definition;
```

This iterative random selection always selects the first item, has a 1/2 chance of replacing it with the second item, a 1/3 for the third, and so on.

Comment: Love the algorithm - had to think about it for a minute to be convinced that it was "fair" - which may simply mean I'm a bit slower than most. :-)

Comment: @Marty me too first time I saw it.  proof: if there's 1 element, it is the selected one.  if you have a fairly randomly selected element of N elements, and you add a N+1th, then 1/(N+1) of the time you should select the new element; the rest of the time (N/(N+1) of the time), you keep the previously selected one, changing its probability from 1/N to (1/N)(N/(N+1)) = 1/(N+1).

Comment: That's interesting. At first I thought the algorithm was all dumb, but I now see that for the price of a whole lot of extra calls to `rand()` and assignments to `$definition`, the memory footprint is kept very small and there are no additional `seek` commands required. Depending on your constraints, that could be very useful.

Comment: @Mort: it isn't a whole lot more assignments to definition unless you strike it really unlucky; if there are 10000 definitions, on average it will be assigning to $definition for 10 of them.